# Custom pagination with URL parameters

Tags: pagination

I want to use URL parameters to define pagination pages like this `/blogroll/?page=1`, `/blogroll/?page=2`, `/blogroll/?page=n..` instead of the conventional Wordpress way `/blogroll/page/2/`

In the same time, I want to preserve the normal permalink structure: `/sample-post/`

The goal is to make Wordpress change the way it manages pagination

`/blogroll/page/2/`

to

`/blogroll/?page=2`

I am happy also with this variant:

`/blogroll/page/2/?page=2`

if necessary.

Comment: Not really sure I understand the question. If you would like to use an URL like `posts?paged=2` you just need to go in under `Settings > Permalinks` and set `Common settings` to `Plain`.

Comment: @Cyclonecode I added a scope: "I want to preserve the permalink structure as `/sample-post/`", also, I am happy to append parameters on the existent structure like this `/blogroll/page/2/?page=2`

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @jdm2112 there is not much to try, it's a setting and to alter a setting I need more info on where to start. I also searched for it and not finding anything that can solve this. It might be a function that I don't know about

Comment: You could try to use the `paginate_links` filter, but still a rewrite seems do be done anyways e.g `add_filter('paginate_links', function ($link) {
  return str_replace('/page/', '?paged=', $link); 
}, 10, 2);`

Comment: @Cyclonecode please see this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/379921/add-parameters-to-paginated-pages-to-avoid-indexing-random-pages-on-google-searc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inject pagination parameters into permalink structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/379921/inject-pagination-parameters-into-permalink-structure)

Comment: @NathanJohnson the question you suggested has no answer yet